# Can I add inputs from different accounts coming from the same Bitcoin HDWallet?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

Say I have 1000 users, each one with its own account with paths m/49'/0'/{user.id}', and I am controlling received/sent funds.

Could I collect all the funds (i.e. inputs) in a sole fat transaction output even though they belong to different accounts of the same HD Wallet?

Comment: note that since you are using hardened keys at the user level public derivation won't be possible. if you instead use non-hardened keys at that level you can store the xpub for m/49'/0'/ on the server and and derive addresses for user level accounts. it's safer than storing the xpriv on a server which you would need to do for hardened derivation.

Comment: It might be, but that'd deviate from the standard, which would make the wallet much harder to export and manipulate in a different scenario, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Each input has its own signature with which to sign, so as long as you possess the private keys (or a master private key above the account level), you can add those inputs into any transaction you want.